# PlayApps issue in production

Tags: playframework

I have installed playapps module locally:

```
`play install playapps`
```

and added in application.conf this line (to be able to use `playapps:deploy`)

> module.playapps=${play.path}/modules/playapps-1.4

Well, after deploying the project in production, I received this error:

`Module playapps will not be loaded because /opt/playapps.net/versions/play-1.2.3/modules/playapps-1.4 does not exist`

Can you suggest any solution? I cannot install this module on `playapps` ssh, it says `play command not found`.

Answer (score 1):

After having this issue myself I finally set the logging level to info and saw: "Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.playapps)".

So rather than following the guide and adding:

```
module.playapps=${play.path}/modules/playapps-1.4
```

Instead you should update the dependencies.yml file with:

```
- play -> playapps 1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `play install playapps`command before and include all configuration in you `application.conf` file refering to the playapps environment.